# SAS blanks between 2 proc reports

Tags: sas, proc-report

I have ods HTML email sender, in which i have included 2 proc reports:

```
ods html file=sendmail;

proc report data=h2 headskip headline spacing=100;
column d1 d2 d3;

define d3/group noprint;
define d1/display left;
define d2/display center;

break afetr gr/;
compute after gr;
line " ";
endcomp;

compute before _page_ /style=[color=red] line;
line "abcdefg";
endcomp;
run;

proc report data=h3 noheader nocenter spacing=100;
column r1;

define r1/display style=[color='green'];

compute before _page_ /style=[color=red] line;
line "qwerty123";
endcomp;
run;

ods html close;
ods listing;
```

As a result i get 2 reports, but there is a huge blanks between them, like extra blank rows or place for titles.
How can i put reports strictly one under another (with only 1 blank line)?
thx in advance

Comment: There are errors in your code. For example, you are grouping by a variable "gr" that is not in the table "h2". "line" after the styles give me errors. When I make some corrections, I run the code and There is not a huge blanks between the 2 reports.

Answer (score 0):

After removing some errors in the code, I don't see any big blanks between the two reports.

```
data h2;
    input d1 $ d2 $ d3 $;
datalines;
aa    ss    ff
bb    qq    ff
cc    yy    dd
dd    dd    dd
;
run;

data h3;
    input r1 $;
datalines;
gg
hh
jj
tt
;
run;

ods html file="thePath\sendmail.html";

proc report data=h2 headskip headline spacing=100;
column d1 d2 d3;

define d3/group noprint;
define d1/display left;
define d2/display center;

break after d3/;
compute after d3;
line " ";
endcomp;

compute before _page_ /style=[color=red];
line "abcdefg";
endcomp;
run;

proc report data=h3 noheader nocenter spacing=100;
column r1;

define r1/display style=[color=green];

compute before _page_ /style=[color=red];
line "qwerty123";
endcomp;
run;

ods html close;
ods listing;
```

Is that what are you looking for ?